# Upload Stem Cell Error - Keystone connection timed out

Tags: openstack, cf-bosh

I am getting a connection timeout error while uploading the stemcell to bosh director. I am using bosh cli v2. The following is myerror logs.

```
> bosh -e sdp-bosh-env upload-stemcell https://bosh.io/d/stemcells/bosh-openstack-kvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent?v=3541.12 --fix


Using environment '10.82.73.8' as client 'admin'

Task 13

Task 13 | 05:02:40 | Update stemcell: Downloading remote stemcell (00:00:51)
Task 13 | 05:03:31 | Update stemcell: Extracting stemcell archive (00:00:03)
Task 13 | 05:03:34 | Update stemcell: Verifying stemcell manifest (00:00:00)
Task 13 | 05:03:35 | Update stemcell: Checking if this stemcell already exists (00:00:00)
Task 13 | 05:03:35 | Update stemcell: Uploading stemcell bosh-openstack-kvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent/3541.12 to the cloud (00:10:41)
               L Error: CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::CloudError' with message 'Unable to connect to the OpenStack Keystone API http://10.81.102.5:5000/v2.0/tokens
Connection timed out - connect(2) for 10.81.102.5:5000 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)' in 'create_stemcell' CPI method


Task 13 | 05:14:16 | Error: CPI error 'Bosh::Clouds::CloudError' with message 'Unable to connect to the OpenStack Keystone API http://10.81.102.5:5000/v2.0/tokens
Connection timed out - connect(2) for 10.81.102.5:5000 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)' in 'create_stemcell' CPI method

Task 13 Started  Sat Apr  7 05:02:40 UTC 2018
Task 13 Finished Sat Apr  7 05:14:16 UTC 2018
Task 13 Duration 00:11:36
Task 13 error



Uploading remote stemcell 'https://bosh.io/d/stemcells/bosh-openstack-kvm-ubuntu-trusty-go_agent?v=3541.12':
Expected task '13' to succeed but state is 'error'

Exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check OpenStack's security group for the BOSH Director machine.
SG should contain `ALLOW IPv4 to 0.0.0.0/0`, if it doesn't add at least egress TCP to 10.81.102.5 on port 5000.

Check connection using ssh:

- `bbl ssh --director`
- `nc -tvn 10.81.102.5 5000`

If it doesn't help check network/firewall configuration.

- https://bosh.io/docs/uploading-stemcells/
- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-bootloader/blob/master/terraform/openstack/templates/resources.tf